# Can't get std::map to insert from function

Tags: function, class, c++14, stdmap

I am trying to add items to a map that is a private variable in a class based on if certain parameters are met. When I try to use the **insert** function for `std::map` or the `[]` operator, nothing happens. I don't even get an error. During debugging the code executes like everything is fine but the map stays empty.

I have tried multiple ways to insert to the map including the [] operator and different insert arguments.

```c
    class foo {
    private:
       std::map<std::string, int> map;

    public:
       void bar();
    };
```

In cpp file:

```c
    void foo::bar() {
       if(condition)
            map.insert(std::make_pair("string", 1));
    }
```

There are no error messages or warnings in the compiler or during debugging.

Comment: Have you verified that the `condition` is actually ever true? With this limited example, it's difficult to conclude anything other than the `insert()` is never called.

Comment: put the debug point at line `map.insert(std::make_pair("string", 1));` and see if it ever stops. If not, the problem is with the condition.

Comment: also try giving another name to `map`. something like `mp` for example.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. Yes, the line does get reached in the code. The insert change is just not reflected in the map.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It sounds like your real code is more complicated than this and a simple example might work fine, then you can figure out what's different in the more complex code. It's often a container being passed by copy so that the copy is modified and the original is not.

Comment: If the standard map usage works, maybe the problem sits in your condition implementation.

Answer (score -1):

If the basic STD map usage works, maybe the problem sits in your `condition` implementation

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>

    class Foo {
      std::map<std::string, int> map;

     public:
      void bar();
      void print();
    };

    void Foo::bar() {
      // if (condition) // weird condition causing failure
      map.insert(std::make_pair("string", 1));
    }

    void Foo::print() {
      std::cout << map.size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << map.at("string") << std::endl;
    }

    int main(void) {
      Foo foo;

      foo.bar();
      foo.print();
    }
```